# PHP: Why can't a static variable in a class be used as a variable function?

Tags: php, function, variables, static

I'm new to using static methods & properties in classes. What I'm trying to do is run a [variable function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php), but can't use:

```
self::$static_var()
```

PHP throws a notice:

```
Undefined variable: static_var
```

I have to first assign to a local variable like so:

```
$local_var = self::$static_var;
```

Then I can do

```
$local_var();
```

Here's some example code. <strike>I don't understand why **Test 1** doesn't work. I have to do **Test 2** in order to get the desired functionality.</strike>  ***Question:*** Why is it that **Test 1** doesn't work?

#### Test 1 - doesn't work

```
X::do_stuff('whatever');

class X {
    public static $static_var = 'print_r';

    public static function do_stuff($passed_var) {
        self::$static_var($passed_var);
    }
}
```

#### Test 2 - works

```
X::do_stuff('whatever');

class X {
    public static $static_var = 'print_r';

    public static function do_stuff($passed_var) {
        $local_var = self::$static_var;
        $local_var($passed_var);
    }
}
```

Comment: try `call_user_func(self::$static_var, $passed_var)`

Comment: Sorry, @Shikiryu. I edited the Question for you.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`call-user-func`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php):

```
call_user_func(self::$static_var, $passed_var);
```

Concerning your edited question:

I tried to find an explanation in PHP docs. It is probably because `$static_var` is not yet evaluated when the function call is processed. But the best answer to your question is probably: because it's the way it is. A good example is: `$classname::metdhod();` was not valid before PHP 5.3. Now it is. There is really no reason why. You should ask the PHP guys.

Comment: Thanks. I edited my Question to be more specific. I'm not trying to look for a work around (as I've already outlined one), I'm just trying to *understand* why Test 1 doesn't work.